# How do I return Unique values only in an Access query for a specific field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query for which I'd like to have it return Unique values only for Expr1

```
SELECT 
[tblA].fldA, 
[tblA].fldB, 
[tblA].fldC, 
[tblB].fldD, [tblB].fldE, 
[tblB].fldF, IIf([fldC]="CAO",[fldB]+" / "+[fldF],IIf([fldC]="PAX",[fldB]+" / "+[fldE],IIf([fldC]="LTQ",[fldB]+" / "+[fldD]))) AS Expr1
FROM 
tblA LEFT JOIN tblB ON [tblA].fldA = [tblB].[fldA];
```

Using DISTINCT will not work here because I want unique values for Expr1
So my question is:
Is there a way to have this query return only unique values for the last column "Expr1"?

Comment: Sure, if you know what you want to do with the other rows.

Comment: Thanks HoneyBadger! Now I see the problem. I should just take away the other columns. `SELECT DISTINCT
[tblB].fldF, IIf([fldC]="CAO",[fldB]+" / "+[fldF],IIf([fldC]="PAX",[fldB]+" / "+[fldE],IIf([fldC]="LTQ",[fldB]+" / "+[fldD]))) AS Expr1
FROM 
tblA LEFT JOIN tblB ON [tblA].fldA = [tblB].[fldA];`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this: You can't. At least not in the way you described it.

Why? Because you will need to figure out the rule for the last column (or last few), for it to only return once. Whether it'll be maximum value or any other, does not matter, but it will need to be grouped.

Alternatively, you can always make the `DISTINCT` a subquery, inside of the `WHERE` clause to get the `IDs` of the rows, which match your criteria, using `IN`.